# Sequential HTTP request in IONIC2/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building a mobile app for my ecom store. 
Most of the app is done but now when we are integrating we are facing some issues, its mostly related to multiple http requests. (correct me if i am wrong) I think they happen sequentially or one wait for the other to send the response.

Here is the issue, on the landing page of the app we have couple of section which requests server to send the data. First time when we get the data we cache the data in the localstorage for faster load later on.

Now the problem occurs when you navigate to a different section and that section also has to do some http request. Then that page takes a lot of time to show the data.

There are 4 http requests from the landing page.

Lets say they are `A,B,C and D`

And there is a page called as new arrivals and it makes one request to get the latest updates from the server, this request is `E`

So if a user opens the app then the http requests would be executed in following order

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

And then if user decides to navigate to new arrivals page then there is one more http request added in the queue

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

So now user has to wait for each http request to complete to get the response. It takes a lot of time for the new arrivals page content to load. But if i disable the landing page http requests and then i do the whole thing again the new arrivals page loads a lot faster. I am guess since it was first in the queue.

Why is this happening?? Am i doing something wrong? or there is a way to change this behavior?

Added code sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-landing',
  templateUrl: 'landing.html',
  providers: [HomePageProducts,General,Auth,Crop,Products],
})
export class Landing {
 public products1 :any;
 public products2 :any;
 public products3 :any;
 public products4 :any;

 constructor(private productService:Products){
  loadProducts();
 }

 loadProducts(){
  this.productService.getPOTW().then((data) => {
   this.products1 = data;
  })
  this.productService.getBestSeller().then((data) => {
   this.products2 = data;
  })
  this.productService.getFeatured().then((data) => {
   this.products3 = data;
  })
  this.productService.getOnSale().then((data) => {
   this.products4 = data;
  })
 }
}
```

**UPDATE 11-01-2017**

Here is a test result after i did the above test in browser as suggested by few members:

Result 1 
https://gyazo.com/1efc3fec9ea339bc46be46758552e31c

Here if you see the highlighted request was fired before the requests below it but it waited until the others finished and then we got the response for it

Result 2:
https://gyazo.com/3c14a4e4aad57256f843b57a2288f4cf

Here i disabled the other requests and tested again. And if you see the same requests returns a response faster than earlier.

The whole thing that i want to know is, does angular2 in any ways process the http requests and response in any sequence? or they are processed in sequence.

Can we do anything to disable this behavior? I mean that's why we fire ajax request to get async response and update the content without waiting for other response.

Comment: You'll have to provide code. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your issue. There's a good chance you'll find the issue while preparing it.

Comment: Why would navigating to a new page would require you to load `ABCD` again? As far as angular is concerd, its a SPA, and you can always store these results in a service or  a factory.

Comment: @jcaron I have added a minimal code but then this is just a question of how it executes does not depends on a code.

Comment: @CozyAzure no, it would not load ABCD again but then since it was initiated by landing page it would still be in the queue.

Comment: @CozyAzure Atleast thats how i have been seen it behaving. I might be doing something wrong or missed something.

Comment: Have you tried checking network requests / timeline in your favorite web inspector, to see which requests are executed, when, in what order, and how long they take?

Comment: Try placing your http calls into ionViewDidEnter callbacks, so your calls wouldn't delay navigating between pages

Comment: Very sorry for being so late on this but this is the the result of the test i did on browser: